# $model.show() returning model is undifined in vue-js-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I keep getting the following error in the console when I click the button to $model.show('demo-login'):

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined`

**Full output on button click:**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
    at click (product.vue?1da5:1)
    at ie (vue.runtime.esm.js:1854)
    at HTMLButtonElement.i (vue.runtime.esm.js:2179)
    at HTMLButtonElement.Jr.a._wrapper (vue.runtime.esm.js:6917)
re @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1888
ne @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1879
ee @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1839
ie @ vue.runtime.esm.js:1862
i @ vue.runtime.esm.js:2179
Jr.a._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js:6917
```

**My code:**

product.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="app">
        <demo-login-modal/>
        <button @click="$model.show('demo-login')">PP</button>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import DemoLoginModal from '@/components/Modal_Login.vue';
export default {
  name: 'product',
  components: {
    DemoLoginModal,
  },
};
</script>
```

Main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Product from '@/components/product.vue';
import VModal from 'vue-js-modal';

Vue.use(VModal);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(Product),
}).$mount('#app');
```

The PopUp in a copy of [Model_login](https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-modal/blob/master/demo/src/components/Modal_Login.vue)

GitHub issue: https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-modal/issues/609

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think you made a typo here

```
<button @click="$model.show('demo-login')">PP</button>
```

change to

```
<button @click="$modal.show('demo-login')">PP</button>
```